# How can I set ComboBox DataContext that was loaded from a file, in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to understand Binding so I have come up with a very simple program to try and test it.

I have the following element in my MainWindow:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" />
```

In my Code I have the following observable collections:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<string> comboItems = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItems
{
    get {return comboItems; }
}
```

I can successfully add items this way at any point during runtime as long as the combobox was in the MainWindow XAML from the very beginning:

```
ComboItems.Clear();
ComboItems.Add("Item");
```

My question is, how can I get this ComboBox to update if I load it from a file?  I have the following code to save and load the file:

```
File.WriteAllText("ComboBox.xaml", saveComboBox)
```

This is just the last line in my save I have other items that don't seem to matter for this discussion.

```
ComboBox comboBox = System.Windows.Markup.Xamlreader.Load(stream) as ComboBox;
```

This saves and loads my combobox successfully.
The problem I am encountering now is that the code:

```
ComboItems.Clear();
ComboItems.Add("Item");
```

No longer works.  I am in the process of trying to learn Data Binding for a new project that I will be doing.  This project will require the loading of xaml files for the user interface and I need to fill the ComboBox after it has been loaded.

What is the simplest and most efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: You collection code was kind of horrible so i changed it, fields usually should not be public, also if you have a setter implement [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). (Also please refrain from "Hi"s and "Thank You"s.)

Comment: I appreciate you correcting me.  I've only been working on WPF for a few months and I have been teaching myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the `XamlReader` will even preserve the bindings, read the documentation, it has limitations. I would not recommend doing this anyway. If the binding is gone you *could* create a new one in code, partially defeats the purpose of saving it of course.

Comment: Sorry.  I should have been more specific.  The combo box shows up in my window because I call MainGrid.Children.Add(cmbBox).  However, there are not items in the dropdown.

Comment: @B-Rad: I don't know if the XamlReader will even preserve the bindings, read the documentation, it has limitations. I would not recommend doing this anyway. If the binding is gone you *could* create a new one in code, partially defeats the purpose of saving it of course.

Comment: Very good point H.B.!  I will take a look and see if the Binding is being preserved.  That very well could be the problem.

Comment: I was just looking at the saved XAML and it appears that you are right.  Bindings are not preserved.